# Can I get location of Aruco markers on Rviz using aruco_ros?

Tags: ros, aruco, moveit

[Simulation on Rviz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLCVr.jpg)

I have the robotic arm simulation like that, I want to localizate the environment using Aruco markers and aruco_ros package. I think that I will be able to get location data of arucos and press the buttons by writing Python code and using aruco's data. Also, ı should solve some objectives such as lifting imu module etc. Is it possible to do something like this? (the simulation has a camera on the gripper)

Comment: From [aruco_ros](https://github.com/pal-robotics/aruco_ros) it seems that there is a TF being published for the aruco tags, With that you have the location that you need. Is that what you asked?

Comment: @ignacio yes i think